# AWK - print certain lines but without being processed

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

If I had a file in the following format:

```
line1 column1
line2 columnA
line3 column1A
exclude this
line5 column2
line6 columnB
line7 column2B
```

I want to swap the columns, so `column*` gets printed before `line*`. I use a simple `awk` command like this: `awk '{print $2 " " $1}'` and get an output like this:

```
column1 line1
columnA line2
column1A line3
this exclude
column2 line1
columnB line2
column2B line3
```

now I want the line with `exclude` to be printed but not resorted (it is not necessarily line 3). I could use this command to ignore the lines: `awk '/exclude/{next}{print $2 " " $1}'` and I get an output without the excluded line:

```
column1 line1
columnA line2
column1A line3
column2 line1
columnB line2
column2B line3
```

How can I tell `awk` to print those line containing `exclude` but not resort the columns? So I would get an output like this:

```
column1 line1
columnA line2
column1A line3
exclude this
column2 line1
columnB line2
column2B line3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
awk '{if(/exclude/){print}else{print $2,$1}}' file.txt
```

Or, same result, but a little shorter.

```
awk '!/exclude/{$0=$2FS$1}1' file.txt
```

Comment: Uuuh, this looks really condensed. For teaching purposes you should rather separate the tokens by spaces, tomakethecodeeasierreadable.